# can't hide elements using jquery and twig

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

I'm trying to hide an element called request-form-display from a page depending if I use the minus button or the plus button. I used diferent ways googling, but I get the same results. I'm talking about something like this:

```
   if($('.plus{{i}}').data('clicked')) {
        $('#request-form-display{{i}}').show();
    };
    if($('.minus{{i}}').data('clicked')){
        $('#request-form-display{{i}}').hide();
    }
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus plus{{i}}"></i>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus{{i}}" style="display: none"></i>
```

the complete code context:

```
{% set i=1 %}
{% for product in products %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{product.code}}</td>
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.typeString}}</td>
        <td>{{product.node?product.node.name}}</td>
        <td id="pp" class="text-right"  >
            {% if request is defined %}
                <a title="Create request" 
                   class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
                   onclick="javascript:loadModal($('#request-form-display{{i}}') ,'{{path('userBuyerProductRequestQuickCreate', {productId: product.id, bidId:bidId})}}');window.location='#productsSearchTable';$('.plus{{i}}').hide();$('.minus{{i}}').show();$('#request-form-display{{i}}').show();if($('.plus{{i}}').data('clicked')) {
                   $('#request-form-display{{i}}').show();
                   };
                   if($('.minus{{i}}').data('clicked')){
                   $('#request-form-display{{i}}').hide();
                   }">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus plus{{i}}"></i>
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus{{i}}" style="display: none"></i>
                </a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <div class="table">
                    <div id="request-form-display{{i}}" style="display:none"></div>
                    {% set i=i+1 %}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help to solve your problem

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showDiv('{{ person.name }}');">{{ person.name }}</a>
```

hidden div

```
<div id="{{ person.name }}" hidden  class="hidden-div">
information for that person
<div>
```

script code to show your div

```
function showDiv(name) {
$("#"+name).show();
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation how this will solve a problem.